# Why this form is submitted also if this script forbids the submission?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, jquery-events

I am absolutely new in JavaScript development and I have the following problem.

I have a form containing two input tags where the user can insert two dates (something like **dateFrom** and **dateTo**) using a calendar script visualization and a submit button (named **Cerca**).

When the user click the submit button it is performed a JavaScript that check if the two dates are correct (if both the dates are set and if the **dateTo** is later the **dateFrom**). If the two dates are correct the form is submitted to a Java Servlet, otherwise it is not submitted.

So this is my form (`dataDa` means **dateFrom** and `dataA` means **dateTo**):

```
<form id="dataDaAForm" name="dataDaAForm" action="salwf.do?serv=<%=request.getSession(false).getAttribute("service")%>&matricola=<%=request.getSession(false).getAttribute("matricola")%>" method="post">
                <div class="customPanel" style="width: 100% !important; overflow-y: auto;">

                    <div class="pane">
                        <table class="dataDaATable" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <!-- DATA DA: -->
                                <td align="right">
                                    Da:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="hidden" size="9" class="impPrfTot" readonly="readonly"
                                           onchange="cambioDataDa(this.value)"
                                           name="dataDa" id="datada" value=""
                                           style="font-size: 11px;color: #000000;">
                                    <input id="datada2" onchange="" type="text" maxlength="9" size="9"
                                           class="impPrfTot"
                                           readonly="readonly" style="width: 100px" value="<%=request.getSession(false).getAttribute("dataDa")%>"
                                           style="font-size: 11px;color: #000000;">

                                    <img style="cursor:pointer;margin-left: 3px;"
                                         src="js/calendar/cal.gif"
                                         alt="Seleziona data" border="0"
                                         onClick="displayCalendar(document.getElementById('datada'),'yyyymmdd',this)">
                                </td>

                                <!-- DATA A: -->
                                <td align="right">
                                    A:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="hidden" size="9" class="impPrfTot" readonly="readonly"
                                           onchange="cambioDataA(this.value)"
                                           name="dataA" id="dataa" value=""
                                           style="font-size: 11px;color: #000000;">
                                    <input id="dataa2" onchange="" type="text" maxlength="9" size="9"
                                           class="impPrfTot" value="<%=request.getSession(false).getAttribute("dataA")%>"
                                           readonly="readonly" style="width: 100px"
                                           style="font-size: 11px;color: #000000;">

                                    <img style="cursor:pointer;margin-left: 3px;"
                                         src="js/calendar/cal.gif"
                                         alt="Seleziona data" border="0"
                                         onClick="displayCalendar(document.getElementById('dataa'),'yyyymmdd',this)">
                                </td>

                                <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON: -->
                                <td>
                                    <button class="dataDadataAButton" name="submitdataDadataA" onclick="testSubmit();">Cerca</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>
```

And this is the script that check if the two dates are correct:

```
function testSubmit() {
        //f = document.forms[0];
        var f = document.getElementById('dataDaAForm');

        //var dataConfermaDA = f.dataDa.value;
        //var dataConfermaA = f.dataA.value;

        var dataDa = f.dataDa.value;
        var dataA = f.dataA.value;

        // TODO:
        if (!controllaDate(dataDa, dataA, "'Data Conferma'")) {
            return false;
        }

        //f.action = "edimon.do?serv=M.5";
        f.submit();
    }


    function controllaDate(DataDA, DataA, nomeCampo) {
        var check_DataDA = (DataDA != "");
        var check_DataA = (DataA != "");

        var check_data_DA = check_DataDA;
        var check_data_A = check_DataA;

        if (!check_data_DA && (check_DataA)) {
            alert(nomeCampo + " Selezionare correttamente Data Da");
            return false;
        }
        if (!check_data_A && (check_DataDA)) {
            alert(nomeCampo + " Selezionare correttamente Data A");
            return false;
        }
        if (check_data_DA && check_data_A) {
            /**
            var giorno = DataDA.substr(6, 7);
            var mese = DataDA.substr(4, 5);
            var anno = DataDA.substr(0, 4);
            var dataDa = new Date(anno, mese - 1, giorno);

            var giorno = DataA.substr(6, 7);
            var mese = DataA.substr(4, 5);
            var anno = DataA.substr(0, 4);
            */

            var giorno = DataDA.substring(6, 8);
            var mese = DataDA.substring(4, 6);
            var anno = DataDA.substring(0, 4);
            var dataDa = new Date(anno, mese - 1, giorno);

            var giorno = DataA.substring(6, 8);
            var mese = DataA.substring(4, 6);
            var anno = DataA.substring(0, 4);

            var dataA = new Date(anno, mese - 1, giorno);
            if (dataA < dataDa) {
                alert(nomeCampo + " La Data Da deve essere minore o uguale alla Data A");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So, for example if I try to insert only the `dataDa` (dateFrom) value and not the `dataA` (dateTo) value what it happens is that when I click the **Cerca** button the `testSubmit()` JavaScript is performed.

Now in this script I have something like this:

```
dataDa = "20141202"
dataA = ""
```

(`dataDa` is set and `dataA` is empty)

So now it is called the `controllaDate()` script that perform the effective date checking.

So this script receives something like this (the received input parameters):

```
controllaDate("20141202", "", "'DataConferma'")
```

So executes this code snippet:

```
if (!check_data_A && (check_DataDA)) {
    alert(nomeCampo + " Selezionare correttamente Data A");
    return false;
}
```

and enter in this if (because `check_data_A` is false because `dataA` is not set).

So show the alert popup and `return false` to its caller that is the `testSubmit()` function.

So, as I expect, now come back to the `testSubmit()` in this point:

```
if (!controllaDate(dataDa, dataA, "'Data Conferma'")) {
    return false;
}
```

and the `testSubmit()` function return `false` and should not submit my form because this operation is not performed:

```
f.submit()
```

But I don't know why the form is submitted anyway also if the `f.submit()` statement is not performed. Why? What am I missing?

Can I prevent in someway the form submitting when return false?

Answer (score 2):

```
<button class="dataDadataAButton" name="submitdataDadataA" onclick="testSubmit();">Cerca</button>
```

You have a submit button. Clicking it will submit the form unless something prevents it.

The `onclick` function calls `testSubmit` (which returns `false`) but it does nothing with the return value from `testSubmit`. You have to return `false` from the `onclick` function  to prevent the normal action of the submit button from happening.

```
onclick="return testSubmit();"
```

---

That said, `onclick` attributes are how we bound JavaScript to event handlers in the 90s. We have [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) now (and we can bind to the `submit` event of the form instead of assuming it will only be submitted by clicking a button).

Comment: mmm it is pretty clear for me what do you mean but can you show me a code snippet to solve my issue? Tnx

Comment: I did. Just before the final paragraph of the answer.